# Match element with array of object and push to new Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an array of object as,

```
const attachmentData = [{name: 'Suman Baidh',attachment: ["123","456"]},
                        {name: 'John Sigma',attachment: ["789","101112]},
                        {name: 'Binay', attachment: ["131415","161718","192021]}]
```

And another array of object as,

```
const attachmentDetail = [{"id":"123",details:{"cost":10,"quantity":20}},
                          {"id":"456",details: {"cost":15,"quantity":28}},
                          {"id":"789",details:{"cost":4,"quantity":9}},
                          {"id":"101112",details:{"cost":40,"quantity":2}},
                          {"id":"131415",details:{"cost":12,"quantity":9}},
                          {"id":"161718",details:{"cost":45,"quantity":2}},
                          {"id":"192021",details:{"cost":120,"quantity":1}}]
```

I want the O/P as: Such that the id which is matched with attachmentDetail also has name along with it and pushed to new array.

```
      [{"name":"Suman Baidh","id":"123","cost":10,"quantity":20},
       {"name":"Suman Baidh","id":"456","cost":15,"quantity":28},
       {"name":"John Sigma","id":"789","cost":4,"quantity":9} ,
       {"name":"John Sigma","id":"101112","cost":40,"quantity":2}, 
       {"name":"Binay","id":"131415","cost":12,"quantity":9}, 
       {"name":"Binay","id":"161718","cost":45,"quantity":2}, 
       {"name":"Binay","id":"192021","cost":120,"quantity":1}]
```

For this I tried as,

```
let newArray = []
for(let i = 0;i<attachmentData.length;i++)}{
    for(let j = 0;j<attachmentData[i].attachment.length;j++){
        if(attachmentData[i].attachment[j] == attachmentDetail.id){
            newArray.push(...attachmentData[i], ... attachmentData[i].attachment[j]
        }
    }
}

On console.log(newArray) , its giving me not the answer I wanted. 

If anyone needs any further information, please let me know. Any suggestion would be really helpful.
```

Comment: Your problem is likely that you write `.push(...x, ...y)` instead of `.push({ ...x, ...y })`.

Comment: The main problem with your code is you are iterating attachmentData twice, but it should be like outer loop with attachmentData and inner loop with attachmentDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
const attachmentData = [
  { name: "Suman Baidh", attachment: ["123", "456"] },
  { name: "John Sigma", attachment: ["789", "101112"] },
  { name: "Binay", attachment: ["131415", "161718", "192021"] },
];

const attachmentDetail = [
  { id: "123", details: { cost: 10, quantity: 20 } },
  { id: "456", details: { cost: 15, quantity: 28 } },
  { id: "789", details: { cost: 4, quantity: 9 } },
  { id: "101112", details: { cost: 40, quantity: 2 } },
  { id: "131415", details: { cost: 12, quantity: 9 } },
  { id: "161718", details: { cost: 45, quantity: 2 } },
  { id: "192021", details: { cost: 120, quantity: 1 } },
];

let newArr = [];
attachmentData.forEach(({name, attachment}) => {
    attachment.forEach((id) => {
        const { details: { cost, quantity } } = attachmentDetail.find((item) => item.id === id)
        newArr.push({ name, id, cost, quantity})
    })
})
console.log(newArr)
```

NOTE: Try to use `find`, `map`, `forEach`, `filter` functions to simplify the `for loop` whenever possible.

Comment: I'm sorry I have updated the question. mistakenly I wrote worng expected o/p, could you please have a look

Comment: @SushantRad, updated the answer as well. please check

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

`if (attachmentData[i].attachment[j] === attachmentDetail.id) {`

Here `attachmentDetail` is an array. To access its element you need to use `attachmentDetail[index].id`.

You will need to loop through it to match the `id` from `attachmentData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const attachmentData = [{name: 'Suman Baidh', attachment: ["123", "456"]},
    {name: 'John Sigma', attachment: ["789", "101112"]},
    {name: 'Binay', attachment: ["131415", "161718", "192021"]}];


const attachmentDetail = [{"id": "123", details: {"cost": 10, "quantity": 20}},
    {"id": "456", details: {"cost": 15, "quantity": 28}},
    {"id": "789", details: {"cost": 4, "quantity": 9}},
    {"id": "101112", details: {"cost": 40, "quantity": 2}},
    {"id": "131415", details: {"cost": 12, "quantity": 9}},
    {"id": "161718", details: {"cost": 45, "quantity": 2}},
    {"id": "192021", details: {"cost": 120, "quantity": 1}}];

let newArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < attachmentData.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < attachmentData[i].attachment.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < attachmentDetail.length; ++k) {
            if (attachmentData[i].attachment[j] === attachmentDetail[k].id) {
                newArray.push({
                    name: attachmentData[i].name,
                    id: attachmentDetail[k].id,
                    ...attachmentDetail[k].details
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

**Or**

```
const attachmentData = [{name: 'Suman Baidh', attachment: ["123", "456"]},
    {name: 'John Sigma', attachment: ["789", "101112"]},
    {name: 'Binay', attachment: ["131415", "161718", "192021"]}];


const attachmentDetail = [{"id": "123", details: {"cost": 10, "quantity": 20}},
    {"id": "456", details: {"cost": 15, "quantity": 28}},
    {"id": "789", details: {"cost": 4, "quantity": 9}},
    {"id": "101112", details: {"cost": 40, "quantity": 2}},
    {"id": "131415", details: {"cost": 12, "quantity": 9}},
    {"id": "161718", details: {"cost": 45, "quantity": 2}},
    {"id": "192021", details: {"cost": 120, "quantity": 1}}];

const newArray = attachmentDetail.map(x => ({
    name: attachmentData.filter(y => y.attachment.includes(x.id))[0].name,
    id: x.id, ...x.details
}));
console.log(newArray);
```

**Output**

```
[
    { name: 'Suman Baidh', id: '123', cost: 10, quantity: 20 },
    { name: 'Suman Baidh', id: '456', cost: 15, quantity: 28 },
    { name: 'John Sigma', id: '789', cost: 4, quantity: 9 },
    { name: 'John Sigma', id: '101112', cost: 40, quantity: 2 },
    { name: 'Binay', id: '131415', cost: 12, quantity: 9 },
    { name: 'Binay', id: '161718', cost: 45, quantity: 2 },
    { name: 'Binay', id: '192021', cost: 120, quantity: 1 }
]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have updated the question. mistakenly I wrote worng expected o/p, could you please have a look

Comment: @SushantRad I've changed my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this will work!

```js
const attachmentData = [
  { name: "Suman Baidh", attachment: ["123", "456"] },
  { name: "John Sigma", attachment: ["789", "101112"] },
  { name: "Binay", attachment: ["131415", "161718", "192021"] },
];

const attachmentDetail = [
  { id: "123", details: { cost: 10, quantity: 20 } },
  { id: "456", details: { cost: 15, quantity: 28 } },
  { id: "789", details: { cost: 4, quantity: 9 } },
  { id: "101112", details: { cost: 40, quantity: 2 } },
  { id: "131415", details: { cost: 12, quantity: 9 } },
  { id: "161718", details: { cost: 45, quantity: 2 } },
  { id: "192021", details: { cost: 120, quantity: 1 } },
];


const newArray = attachmentDetail.map((detail) => {
    const data = attachmentData.find((data) => data.attachment.includes(detail.id));
    return {name: data.name, id: detail.id, ...detail.details}
})
```

Comment: I would like to apologize I have update expected o/p, I wrote wrong expected o/p.Could  you please have a look

Comment: `.find(...)` makes more sense than `.filter(...)[0]`

Comment: Yes, find makes more sense than filter in this case.

Comment: @SushantRad Updated! Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

If we want to deal with two arrays(specially for large sets of data), It's always good to convert one array to object(hash) and iterate over the other to find the matching.

```js
const attachmentData = [{name: 'Suman Baidh',attachment: ["123","456"]}, {name: 'John Sigma',attachment: ["789","101112"]}, {name: 'Binay', attachment: ["131415","161718","192021"]}]
const attachmentDetail = [{"id":"123",details:{"cost":10,"quantity":20}}, {"id":"456",details: {"cost":15,"quantity":28}}, {"id":"789",details:{"cost":4,"quantity":9}}, {"id":"101112",details:{"cost":40,"quantity":2}}, {"id":"131415",details:{"cost":12,"quantity":9}}, {"id":"161718",details:{"cost":45,"quantity":2}}, {"id":"192021",details:{"cost":120,"quantity":1}}];
  
  function customMerge(data, attachments) {
  
    const hashById = attachments.reduce((acc, ele) => {
      acc[ele.id] = ele;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return data.reduce((acc, {attachment, name}) => {
            return acc.concat(attachment.map(id => ({name, id, details: hashById[id].details})));
    },[]);
  }
  
  console.log(customMerge(attachmentData, attachmentDetail))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const attachmentData = [
        { name: 'Suman Baidh', attachment: [ '123', '456' ] },
        { name: 'John Sigma', attachment: [ '789', '101112' ] },
        { name: 'Binay', attachment: [ '131415', '161718', '192021' ] },
    ];
    
    const attachmentDetail = [
        { id: '123', details: { cost: 10, quantity: 20 } },
        { id: '456', details: { cost: 15, quantity: 28 } },
        { id: '789', details: { cost: 4, quantity: 9 } },
        { id: '101112', details: { cost: 40, quantity: 2 } },
        { id: '131415', details: { cost: 12, quantity: 9 } },
        { id: '161718', details: { cost: 45, quantity: 2 } },
        { id: '192021', details: { cost: 120, quantity: 1 } },
    ];
    
    const newArray = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < attachmentData.length; i++) {
        const { attachment } = attachmentData[i];
    
        for (let j = 0; j < attachment.length; j++) {
            attachmentDetail.some(element => {
                if (element.id === attachment[j]) {
                    newArray.push({ name: attachmentData[i].name, ...element });
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a `Map` whose keys are the attachment ids and value is the name corresponding to that attachment.

Then loop over `attachmentDetail` array and just add the `name` using the `Map` created.

```js
const 
  attachmentData = [{ name: "Suman Baidh", attachment: ["123", "456"] }, { name: "John Sigma", attachment: ["789", "101112"] }, { name: "Binay", attachment: ["131415", "161718", "192021"] }],
  attachmentDetail = [{ id: "123", details: { cost: 10, quantity: 20 } }, { id: "456", details: { cost: 15, quantity: 28 } }, { id: "789", details: { cost: 4, quantity: 9 } }, { id: "101112", details: { cost: 40, quantity: 2 } }, { id: "131415", details: { cost: 12, quantity: 9 } }, { id: "161718", details: { cost: 45, quantity: 2 } }, { id: "192021", details: { cost: 120, quantity: 1 } }],
  
  map = attachmentData.reduce((m, o) => (o.attachment.map((a) => m.set(a, o.name)), m), new Map()),
  res = attachmentDetail.map(({ id, details }) => (name => ({ id, name, ...details }))(map.get(id)));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @SushantRad Please check if this solves your problem, let me know if you have any issues.